# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I want to run this LINQ simple code to have record number in LINQ but result is beneath error

```
var model = _db2.Persons.Select(
    (x, index) => new 
    {
        rn = index + 1,
        col1 = x.Id
    }).ToList();
```

Error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`2
>       [System.Int32,System.Int32]] Select[Person,<>f__AnonymousType2`2](System.Linq.IQueryable`1
>       [MvcApplication27.Models.Person], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3
>       [MvcApplication27.Models.Person,System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType2`2
>       [System.Int32,System.Int32]]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store 
>       expression.

Comment: looks like `Persons` is not `IQueryable`, try using `Cast` or `OfType` (of course if they are present) first.

Comment: No, this is because of index to find record number.
This is Code First and i have no problem when i remove index in lambda!

Comment: As a note of your title `System.Linq.IQueryable` is the return type, not the method name. The stuff you see in the square brackets (`[<>f__AnonymousType22 [System.Int32,System.Int32]]`) is the stuff that would be in the `<int,  f__AnonymousType22<>>` if you where to type it out. The actual function is after that section `Select[Person,<>f_AnonymousType22](...)`.

Answer (score 28):

The problem is that LINQ to Entities doesn't understand how to convert that `Select` overload (the one that gives you the index) into a SQL query. You can fix this by first selecting the portion from the DB you need (to avoid selecting every column unnecessarily), then doing `AsEnumerable()` to take it as an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of an `IQueryable<T>`, and then doing the `Select` purely in C# (in short, `IQueryable<T>`s are converted to SQL, while `IEnumerable<T>`s are run in code).

```
var model = _db2.Persons.Select(x => x.Id).AsEnumerable().Select(
    (id, index) => new
    {
        rn = index + 1,
        col1 = id
    }).ToList();
```

Note that the query as you have it appears to be unordered, so the id/index pairings can change each time you call this. If you expected consistency, you should order by something (e.g. `_db2.Persons.OrderBy(...)`).

**Edit**

Adding comment from [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain):

> As a nice reference [here is the list of all Linq statements built in
>   to the framework and a listing if it is compatible or not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx).

Comment: As a nice reference [here is the list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx) of all Linq statements built in to the framework and a listing if it is compatible or not.

Comment: Don't you think that 2 select(select().AsEnumerable().Select()) cause reduce efficiency compare with
equal simple 1 statement SQL?

Comment: @ehsan yes it does, but you can not use the `Select<T, int>(...)` function with Entity framework. You will either need to use the [Query Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx) with [`let`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) or use a more complicated method syntax than what you have (which I think would greatly decrease readability)

Comment: To add to what @ScottChamberlain said, the biggest performance issue here is I/O with the DB. Since we've kept that to a minimum by only selecting the `Id`, the performance here should be practically the same as the best possible LINQ to Entities solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could just select the Id and after it create your own anonymous object using linq to objects, for sample:

```
var model = _db2.Persons.Select(x => x.Id)
                        .ToList() // return int[]
                        .Select((id, index) => new
                                {
                                    rn = index + 1,
                                    col1 = id
                                 }) // return anonymous[] (with rn and col1)
                         .AsEnumerable(); // get an IEnumerable (readonly collection)
```

Problably this is happen because Entity Framework does not support this kind of query using linq as linq could do in memory, so, in this case, you could select just you need (`id` in your case) and execute it, using `ToList()` method to concretize your query and after that you will have a list on memory, so, you can use linq to objects and use the supported method as you want.

Comment: You can `AsEnumerable()` in the middle. You'll have one less `List()`

Comment: It would be nice if you explained *why* you need to do it. (I was attempting to post my own answer saying something similar but I got hung up on how to explain why this is happening to someone who is new to EF)