# How work the method TrueForAll? C# LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to use TrueForAll method, but things are not working very well. Could anyone help me?

My problem:
I have a list of integers, for example, myIntList. I need a certain condition is met for all integers of my list.

Example:

```
List<TABLE1> myFinalList = db.TABLE1
    .Where(myTable1 => 
        myIntList.TrueForAll(myInt => 
            db.TABLE2.Any(myTable2 => 
                myTable2.field1 == myTable1.field1 
                && myTable2.field2 == myInt)
            && db.TABLE3.Any(myTable3 =>
                myTable3.field1 == myTable1.field1 
                && myTable3.field2 == myInt))).ToList();
```

But when I run, I get the following exception:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean TrueForAll[Int32](Int32[], System.Predicate`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I've tried using Array.TrueForAll(), but the error remains

```
... Array.TrueForAll(myIntList.toArray(), myInt => ...
```

Ideas?

Comment: It means your query provider (Entity Framework) can't translate it into proper SQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788784/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-linq-iqueryable)

Comment: although the method you're calling is different, the error, and the solution, are the same as the ones in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788784/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-linq-iqueryable?rq=1  Basically: you can't called TrueForAll inside an Entity-Framework LINQ Query, you have to force it to be a LINQ to Objects query first.

Comment: I tried solve the problem of the TrueForAll() method, but i made work with the All() method. I will study more about TrueForAll() and how his work. But, even so, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the linq All() method.

Answer (score 0):

**Definition:**

List.TrueForAll Method

Determines whether every element in the List matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate.

**Answering your question**

your code looks good. I made a quick test of it (see code below) just be sure that the returned values for the functions (Any) is a Boolean, if you look at the error message it says that an integer (int32) is returned by one of them

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;

var myFinalList = db.Tables[0].Select()
            .Where(myTable1 =>
                myIntList.TrueForAll(myInt =>

                    db.Tables[1].Select().Any(myTable2 =>
                        myTable2["field1"] == myTable1["field1"] &&
                        (int)myTable2["field2"] == myInt)

                    &&

                    db.Tables[2].Select().Any(myTable3 =>
                        myTable3["field1"] == myTable1["field1"] &&
                        (int)myTable3["field2"] == myInt))).ToList();
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I solved the problem using the All() method. I believe that int32 mentioned in exception refers to param type passed to predicate of TrueForAll() method, but even so, thank you.