# nested select projection with index in linq using EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I just modified a linq query to include an index. The index is necessary to help a client web app manage the items returned (adding, removing, updating, duplicating, etc). That part is working with mockup data on the client side, so it needs the same kind of format structure returned from the server. The index should be sequenced as 0,1,2,..

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do:

Lets say I want to find a list of cities in a country that has states/provinces.

So I have the following two classes:

```
public class CityItemDTO {
   public int id { get; set; }
   public City item {get; set; }
}

public class CityDTO {
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string stateName {get; set; }
    public int population {get; set; }
}
```

I want to add the index along with the list of cities and state properties:

```
var cities = context.Countries
    .Where(s => query.Name == s.Name)
    .Select((s,index) => new CityItemDTO
    {
        id = index,
        item = new CityDTO()
        {
            name = s.name,
            stateName = s.stateName
            population = s.population
        }
    });
```

But I get a weird error:

> "Could not parse expression 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[DataService.Models.Countries]).Where(s => (__query_Name_0 == s.Name)).Select((s, index) => new CityItemDTO() {id = index, item = new CityDTO() {Name = s.Name, StateName = s.StateName, Population = s.Population }})': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select' is currently not supported."

However, the following works if I take the index out:

```
var cities = context.Countries
    .Where(s => query.Name == s.Name)
    .Select(s => new CityDTO
    {
        new CityDTO()
        {
            name = s.name,
            stateName = s.stateName
            population = s.population
        }
    });
```

Comment: EF will not turn a `Select` with an index into SQL query.

Comment: But I seen examples that do that though, is there a way I can get the index or is there another way I can do this, I need an index to be added to the solution. Also, why was I downvoted? The question is pretty straight forward.

Comment: In a SQL query there is no index if the table doesn't have one. Are you looking for the `Id` of the city? If so, then does the table have an `Id` column? That could easily be mapped but an arbitrary index is not the same.

Comment: i dont need the id, the index is to keep count of items that were selected, the client is expecting this format.. I might have to convert to a list.. and do another iteration using foreach. This is a runtime error, if this is not possible, this error should have errored out at compile time

Comment: still brutal that i got downvoted just because i didn't know that you cant bring an indexer into a sql statement.. down votes are there for violating stackoverflow policies in asking a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the question has been answered before, because of the new framework, the error message is different, and because of how I got to the answer, thinking that projections where interfering with how the indexer was working.

[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788784/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-linq-iqueryable)

All I had to do was add an AsEnumerable() which converts the result into C# objects, then the select (preserving the logic I originally had) would then add the index to the iterations.

```
var cities = context.Countries
.Where(s => query.Name == s.Name)
.AsEnumerable()    //  where the magic happens
.Select(s => new CityDTO
{
    new CityDTO()
    {
        name = s.name,
        stateName = s.stateName
        population = s.population
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually that LINQ query simply can be translated into indexing row with dbfunction row_number() over () (at least for postgreSQL) but for now (Feb, 2021) still not supported.